# IntelliJ IDEA directory-based format and .iml file(s)

Tags: intellij-idea

We started a directory-based project in IntelliJ IDEA (currently using version `2016.3 build 163.7743.44`). Everything is fine, the `.iml` file is inside `.idea/modules` and we can easily share/update it.

The issue is that, sometimes, when someone clones the project and start using it the IDE doesn't care about that file (or project structure) and puts an `.iml` outside the project's root. It's an intermittent/random issue and I'm not able to reproduce it step by step.

We opted for deleting the `.idea` directory from Git and keep the configurations/settings in a JAR file.

Is there any way to tell the IDE to use one approach or the other? It's not a big deal, but I would like to know what's the reason behind that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that behavior may be that people don't use the "Open" action to open the project but use the "Import project from existing sources" action instead. The latter action does not use the existing .idea directory, but instead recreates the project structure from scratch. You should teach your colleagues not to use that action.

Note that storing the settings in a .jar file is not a replacement for sharing the project structure, because shared settings do not include project-specific items such as libraries and run configurations.